# use of checkEnclosure() and checkIntersection() in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to test for intersection and enclosure of a svg element within a rectangle. I am using the functions checkEnclosure() and checkIntersection() from the SVGSVGElement Web API.

This works in Chrome (kind of, the functions only check the bounding boxes of the element), but for some reason this does not work in Firefox. I don't get an error, just the function exits when it reaches the functions. Here is my code (it is based on Snap.svg, but that is irrelevant):

```
function isInRect(el, rect) {
var box = rect.node.getBBox(); //get a proper SVGRect element
if (el.type == "g") {
    var children = getTopChildren(el);
    for (var i = 0, max = children.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (isInRect(children[i], rect)) return true;
    }
    return false;
} else {
    var node = el.paper.node;
    var checkEnclosure = node.checkEnclosure(el.node, box);
    var checkIntersection = node.checkIntersection(el.node, box);
    return checkIntersection || checkEnclosure;
}
```

I have seen some **old** discussion about this, saying that Firefox lacks some support, but I wonder of there has been some development.

I guess, I could write my own function for this, snap.svg has some reasonable  machinery already inside the Path plugin. However, it is better to rely on the native code for efficiency.

Comment: There has been no development. Feel free to pitch in and do it if you wish, Firefox is open source after all.

Comment: I will not be able to extend the functionality of Firefox, unfortunately. I am not sufficiency versed in C++. But, I will have to add functionality to Snap.svg